# Проверка Pin-кода при возобновлении работы приложения на Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart

При первом запуске приложения написанного на Flutter, пользователю необходимо ввести pin-код, что бы продолжить использовать приложение. Использую плагин [flutter_pin_code_fields](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pin_code_fields) для отображения полей ввода Pin-кода. После использования приложения пользователи чаще всего не закрывают приложение, а просто сворачивают его и в будущем при повторном открытии приложение восстанавливается и открывается с того момента, на котором пользователь его свернул. Как стоит сделать так, что бы при повторном открытии приложения Pin-код снова запрашивался? Как вообще это должно работать и есть ли уже готовые плагины с данной реализацией?

Comment: Если посмотреть на то же сбербанк, то приложении которое свернули не запрашивает пин код (кроме тех случаев когда приложение выгрузилась из памяти). То что вы хотите сделать, сложно реализовать на нативе, что говорить о flutter...

Comment: @MiT ну есть 1 простой вариант, но он костыльный. Суть в следующем: при открытии вкладки во время её инициализации получать время открытия вкладки и сравнивать его со временем предыдущей инициализации. Если время не превышает 10 минут - обновлять время и позволять работать дальше, иначе вызывать меню проверки pin-кода. Метод совсем не большой, но его нужно будет вызывать при инициализации каждой вкладки. Пока что только такой вариант есть. Он работает, но такой  способ далеко не лучший)

Comment: костыль с велосипедом)

Comment: @MiT ну вот и я про то же) думал кто что лучше сможет предложить)